# Seeking QGIS equivalent to Focal Statistics of ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, spatial-analyst

I'm attempting to use QGIS v2.0.1 to accomplish the same tasks that I can do using ArcMap v10.1 and I'm running into some trouble finding equivalent tools. In ArcMap I am using the Focal Statistics (mean) Spatial Analyst tool and I do not know if GRASS or SAGA has an equivalent in QGIS.

Does anyone know what the tool would be called if it exists?

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers!
I'll try it and come back to say if it works well :)

Answer (score 17):

Sure, have for instance a look at the [r.neighbors](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.neighbors.html) tool available through the processing-toolbox with GRASS support enabled.
It has a similar functionality as the Focal Statistics tool. 
I will also soon add a generic filter function to my QGIS plugin LecoS (needs installed Scipy), which can do the same stuff, but uses python+scipy as backbone.

Answer (score 3):

Still in QGIS 2.4 there are no focal statistics, i.e. filters, per se, and I do not think that there will be any in the future. However, SAGA can be reached via the Processing tool box. In the SAGA command list you can choose `Grid - Filter` and then you have plent of a choice. I suggest using the "user defined filter" if you know what you are doing or the "simple filter" if it is all about smoothing.

cheers