# How to sum up values of neighbouring rasters?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster (25X25 meter) and I will make a new raster where each cell get the value of the sum of all the raster cells in a radius of 500m. I use QGIS. What is the best option to do this?

Comment: Ref. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24933/raster-generalization-buffers-in-rasters-expand-pixels and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74592/is-there-a-focal-statistics-spatial-analyst-tool-in-arcgis-equivalent-in-qgis -- the best tool is probably [r.neighbors](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.neighbors.html) (with method sum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a moving analysis window approach (Focal Statistics) to solve this.  You can use the [r.neighbors](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.neighbors.html) tool available in the QGIS GRASS toolkit.  Make sure to specify a sum statistic, a circular neighborhood and the desired neighborhood size.

[image]