# How to reduceresolution of an Image using the most frequent value

Tags: google-earth-engine

Does anyone have an idea how I could aggregate my Image so that in the output the most frequent value is used, as shown on the picture?

[image]

this is the same question as [aggregate raster using the most frequent value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/179961/154945) but using the earthengine API

Comment: Is this for an export or for rendering directly on a map? If export, just set the pyramiding policy to `mode`.

Comment: it's for export, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You control how pixels are aggregated with the `pyramidPolicy` property in exports. In your case, you want to use `mode`.

```
var image = ee.Image('USGS/GFSAD1000_V1')
  .clip(geometry)
  
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: image, 
  pyramidingPolicy: {'.default': 'mode'}, 
  scale: 100000
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/cc36b36bc0d8374dcf3483c87252f0eb

**Update**

When exporting to drive, `pyramidingPolicy` cannot be specified. Something like this could work:

```
var scale = 10000
var image = ee.Image('USGS/GFSAD1000_V1')
  .clip(geometry)
  
  
var reprojected = image
  .reduceResolution({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mode(),
    maxPixels: 65536 // Max input pixels for each output pixel
  })

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: reprojected,
  scale: scale
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4058242ee0216ab76b9343a675066e7d

Comment: if I try to export to drive, I get the following error : `EEException: Unknown configuration options: {'pyramidingPolicy': 'mean'}`.  Is there a trick to use it anyway ?

Comment: I was editing your answer with the exact same solution. The reproject is not needed