# File not found error using Contour in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, csv, error, contour, gdal-contour

CSV file load failure in "Contour" procedure, even though the same file will load and display from Layers>Add Layer>.  This has not previously been true.

The problem could be related to the use of forward slash vs. back slash.

The source window for the Layer load uses back slashes and does work.

The source window for the "Contour" load window uses forward slashes and receives the "can't find file" error.  The slashes are not entered by me.  It is entirely a program generated syntax.  Selection for both methods uses the standard windows file selection window.

I previously noticed a similar error when using GRASS through QGIS, but when I used stand alone GRASS, I had no problem.

Is there a setting that can be changed?  Or does it have a different cause?

Answer (score 2):

Forward slash is not a problem. You are using wrong input. To use `Contour` you need to input raster, CSV file is not really raster.
So you should rasterize your points before using `Contour`. There are already some posts on this topic:

[Generating Contours from csv Concentrations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199096/generating-contours-from-csv-concentrations)

[How to create contour lines from point data using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112890/how-to-create-contour-lines-from-point-data-using-qgis)

If problem persists using correct input, try using the tool in command line: [gdal_contour](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html)